# How do I enable unified audit on oracle DB which is placed in a docker container?

Tags: database, oracle, docker, sqlplus, unified-log

I created an oracle database on docker container using the following command:

```
docker run -d --name oracle -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 quay.io/maksymbilenko/oracle-12c

The db params are:
hostname: localhost
port: 1521
sid: xe
service name: xe
username: system
password: oracle
```

**I would like to enable unified audit, perform a query such as SELECT and see it on the audit log.**

I have access to this DB with sqlplus using the following command:

```
sqlplus system/oracle@//localhost:1521/xe
```

or via the app dbeaver.

First issue:
According to what I have found, in order to enable unified audit I need to Shutdown the database.
This can be done by using sqlplus and running the next command:

```
 shutdown immediate
```

When I did that, the action has failed because: **ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**

*Is there any way that I could just run a regular query to enable the unified audit?
Do I have to shut it off before?*
*Is there any way that I could do all that I want just with running queries? ( enable, create audit and view actions)*

Comment: To start unified auditing you will need to shutdown all the processes by oracle. And yes you will need to use `sysdba` user to shutdown the database. Refer this link for entire process: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/security/sec_uni_audit/sec_uni_audit.html

Comment: I tried to run this command in order to connect :sqlplus sysdba/oracle@//localhost:1521/xe but it didn't work,  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: and also if I run it like that: sqlplus / as sysdba I get an error saying ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

Comment: Try `sqlplus sys/oracle@//localhost:1521/xe as sysdba`